# Button Redirect to a controller in Rails Slim template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have a rails controller page home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #@users = User.all
    @loan_applications = LoanApplication.all
  end

  def button_listing_show
    redirect_to lp_banker_assignments_path
  end
end
```

And I have this Rails Slim button code

```
button Go to Listings onclick="<%home.button_listing_show%>"
```

What i want is on the onclick events the page redirects to this path.

Can someone provide an answer for me either in Slim or in Rails.

Thanks

Comment: i don't understand at all what you are asking for.

Comment: It appears he wants to just embed that path into the `onclick`. I'm not familiar with Slim, but a quick scan of the docs says he should just be able to do variable interpolation right in the template. So I've provided an answer to that effect below.

Answer (score 0):

```
button Go to Listings onclick="#{lp_banker_assignments_path}"
```

You are just generating a path with that function, so why not just interpolate to the path directly?

[Docs for variable interpolation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Text_interpolation)